# How to compare a given string with a result

Tags: c

I'm very new to this and to C programming. It's my first year and things are not very clear for me. Hopefully I can get better very soon.

I have a code here where i input a number and I get results based on the table I have below.
I would like to know: If i have a given string (in the code it's: test[7]="2 B 1 C")
How can I compare the result i have to this string and see if it's the same to print=good?

it's very hard to explain so please let me know if i'm not clear with my question. You can test the code to see how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void initialize(int poss[1296][4]);

int main()
 {
  int table[1296][4];
  char str[5];
  char tmp[5];

  int i, j, k;
  int bull = 0;
  int cow = 0;
  char test[7]={"2 B 0 C"};

  initialize(table);
  printf("Enter 4 digits: ");

  scanf("%s", str);

  for (i=0; i<1296; i++)  // building this table
  {
    strcpy(tmp, str);   // copying string

    for (j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<4; k++)
        {
            if (table[i][j]==tmp[k]-'0' && j==k)    // gets the string as an integer
            {
                tmp[k] = -1;
                bull++;
                break;
            }
            else if (table[i][j]==tmp[k]-'0' && j!=k)
            {
                tmp[k] = -1;
                cow++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf ("%d B %d C\n\n", bull, cow);
    bull = 0;
    cow = 0;
  }
}

//------------------------------------TABLE---------------------------------//

void initialize(int poss[1296][4])
 {
int i=0;
int j, k=0;
int m;

while (i<=5)
{
    for (j=0; j<216 ; j++)
    {
        poss[k][0]=i;
        k++;
    }
    i++;
  }

  k=0;
  i=0;
  j=0;

  while (k<1296)
  {
    for (m=0; m<6; m++)
     {
        for (j=0; j<6; j++)
          {
            for (i=0; i<36 ; i++)
              {
                poss[k][1]=j;
                k++;
              }
          }
      }
  }

  k=0;
  i=0;
  j=0;
  m=0;

  while (k<1296)
   {
    for (j=0; j<6; j++)
    {
        for (i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            poss[k][2]=j;
            k++;
        }
    }

  }

  k=0;
  i=0;
  j=0;
  m=0;

  while (k<1296)
  {
    for (i=0; i<6; i++)
      {
        poss[k][3]=i;
        k++;
      }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Just to make it clear the user inputs a number and based on the table it give's a result. (Table gives 1296 possibilities)
example:
1245 // from the user
1354 = 1 B 2 C //(from the table)

Comment: @userXXX Are you looking for the `strcmp()` function?

Comment: yes but i want it to compare to all the results i have

Comment: @userXXX Are you aware of the concept of loops?

Comment: @userXXX Then you can just loop over the results (I suppose you have an array or list, etc. of them) and compare each element with the desired result.

Comment: i want to apply strcmp() my test[7]=..... to all the results so in a way i need my results to be printed out as a string I think.. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: am I mistaken with what I said?

Comment: @userXXX Sorry but I didn't understand that.

Comment: from what i said i need to compare the string there is (test[7]="2 B 0 C") with the results given from my table but i need the result to be set as a string right?

Comment: size of `test[7]` small. I seems like there is no meaning to the display of your code result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sprintf to generate the result into a string instead of printing it, then use strcmp to compare that string to what you expect it to be. You can also then use printf to print the string you produced with sprintf. (When you sprintf, don't include the newlines since those aren't in your test string; only output those with printf).

What's not clear from your question, however, is that you only have one test string but print 1296 lines ... if those lines aren't all the same then you need an array of 1296 test results ... or a clearer question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me try and be a bit more clearer.
Aside from comparing strings, User inputs a number and from the table I get the result. It's a bulls and cows program.
so if user inputs 1100 and from the table is have 1010 the result is 2B2C 2 bulls and 2 cows (2 integers that are in the right position and 2 that are not)

Answer (score 0):

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char test[8]={"2 B 0 C"};
    char result[8];
    int bull = 0;
    int cow = 0;
    bull = 2;//set by program
    cow = 0;
    sprintf(result, "%d B %d C", bull, cow);
    if(strcmp(result, test)==0){
        printf("match!\n");
    } else {
        printf("not match!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```